# Qml XmlListModel with multiple SOURCES

Tags: xml, qt, qml

I do have a bunch of xml files named "config_1.xml", "config_2.xml", "config_3.xml", and so on.

Basically, I need to loop from first one to last one, appending in the SAME XmlListModel all the "id" that I find at the query context/info/parameters in each xml file.

So, once the reading is completed, I will have the whole list of id(s).

I tried with:

```
property int myIterator: 1

Repeater {
    model: 10 //10 is just an example. I have this number in my code by other functions.
    XmlListModel {
        id: myModel
        source: "qrc:/ConfigFiles/config_" + myIterator + ".xml" // <---- THIS IS THE PROPERTY I NEED TO PARAMETRIZE!!!
        query: "context/info/parameters"
        XmlRole { name: "myId"; query: "id/number()" }
        onCountChanged: { ++myIterator; }
    }
}

onMyIteratorChanged: {
    if (myIterator> 10)
        for(var i = 0; i<myModel.count; i++) // myModel.count should be equal to 10!!!
            console.log("id: " + myModel.get(i).myId);
}
```

However, with this code the application crashes.
How can I fix it?

I also considered the idea of transferring all the information stored in myModel at each iteration into a ListModel (in which the appen() is easy by documentation). But I still don't know how to call XmlListModel n times...

Thank you!! :-)

Comment: `myModel` is a identifier of object of type `XmlListModel`. You have to understand that `myModel` isn't array but "pointer" to instance of object. But  `Repeater` is a kind of array in your case. So you can access your object by index using `Repeater.itemAt(index)`

Comment: @folibis, the point to me is the fact that the Repeater needs a delegate of Item type, and not a model. And so I am looking for an alternative solution. How can have n XmlListModel ?

Comment: With an `Instantiator`

Comment: @GrecKo could you explain me a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create multiple `XmlListModel` based on a model, you can't use a `Repeater` since `XmlListModel` is not an `Item`. You have to use [`Instantiator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html) for plain `QtObject`.

Similarly to a `Repeater` you can access the data of a model in the delegate with `modelData` (or `index`, it's the same here since we are using an integer as a model).

If you want to iterate over all your model you can do so with [`count`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html#count-prop) and [`objectAt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html#objectAt-method) :

```
Instantiator {
    id: instantiator
    model: 10
    delegate: XmlListModel {
        source: "qrc:/ConfigFiles/config_" + (modelData + 1) + ".xml"
        query: "context/info/parameters"
        XmlRole { name: "myId"; query: "id/number()" }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (var i = 0; i < instantiator.count; i++) {
            var xmlModel = instantiator.objectAt(i);
            for (var j = 0; i < xmlModel.count; j++)
                console.log("id: " + xmlModel.get(j).myId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @GrecKo